# Get file string in compile time

Tags: c++, macros, c++14, compile-time

file1.cc

```
void func() {
  std::cout << "test\n";
}
```

file2.cc

```
...
std::string str = GET_FILE("file1.cc");
...
```

So, what I need is that `str` has the content of file1.cc as string, in **compile time**, NOT execution time.

How to implement this GET_FILE macro?

Comment: It's impossible. A good alternative is to use `objdump` to put `file1.cc` into an object file and then link with it, as described here: https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/. You'll have a pointer to the data at linking time, but it's impossible to construct `std::string` from it at compilation time.

Comment: You can #include the file with a macro to convert it to a const char*

Comment: @nitronoid It wouldn't work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, it isn't possible, if GET_FILE generates a literal string token "asdf", it could be possible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
#define STR_SOURCE(...) #__VA_ARGS__
...
std::string t = STR_SOURCE(int func() {return 3;})

Comment: You could try `std::string t = STR_SOURCE( #include "file1.cc" )` (make sure the `#include "..."` is on a separate line), but I doubt it would work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , no, It doesn't work. It was only an example, that is possible generate data to std::string on compile time

Comment: @Alex Unless the compiler performs some tricky optimizations, the string will be constructed at runtime, when the program starts. Not at compilation time.

Comment: Have you tried the macro `__FILE__`?  On some platforms or compiler tool sets, the macro will expand to the file name including the path (absolute file name).  Check your compiler macros to see if there is a macro that only returns the base filename (without the path).  Since this is a preprocessor macro, the value is known at compile time.